# A ratio of two series blows up at certain $\epsilon$ values. Why?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, graphing-functions

I am trying to understand the behaviour of this function:

$$f(x)=\frac{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{4}{1+\epsilon hx}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\lambda_n^4}tanh\bigg(\frac{\lambda_n(1+\epsilon hx)}{2}\bigg)}{\frac{1}{3}-\frac{4}{1+\epsilon hx}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\lambda_n^5}tanh\bigg(\frac{\lambda_n (1+\epsilon hx)}{2}\bigg)}$$

Where $\lambda_n=(n+\frac{1}{2})\pi$, and h is a constant.

For $\epsilon=0$, I get a constant horizontal plot, which makes sense.

The more I increase the value of $\epsilon$, the more the graph starts to descend, for example in this case of $\epsilon=0.00001$:

[Graph of $f(x)$ for $\epsilon=0.00001$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7wuJ.jpg)

But at a certain point, the graph starts to fluctuate at a certain $x$ position and blows up. For example, for $\epsilon=0.001$:

[Graph of $f(x)$ for $\epsilon=0.0001$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOeqv.jpg)

It's not an asymptote, the peak of the blow up is at around 6,000,
and the more I decrease the $\epsilon$ value, the lower the peak is at.
My question is this: Why does this behaviour occur?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What software are you using to graph this? Something similar happened to me because I used normal 64 bit floating point numbers. Finite precision numbers can make graphs go crazy, especially where really small or really big numbers are involved.

Comment: I'm using Wolfram Mathematica.
Is there any way to handle this problem, then?

Comment: My guess is that the denominator of $f(x)$ is approaching $0$.

Comment: It might help if you told us the value of $h$.

Comment: The value of $h$ is $10^6$.
$x$ is running between $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say since we do not have any idea about the values of $h$ and $x$ for which you have the problem.

So, let $\delta=\epsilon h x$ and consider
$F(\delta)=\frac AB$ with 
$$A=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{4}{1+\delta}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\lambda_n^4}\tanh\bigg(\frac{\lambda_n(1+\delta)}{2}\bigg)$$
$$B=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{4}{1+\delta}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\lambda_n^5}\tanh\bigg(\frac{\lambda_n (1+\delta)}{2}\bigg)$$ and for conveniency, let me use $\delta=10^k$.

I give below a table of my results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 k & A & B & \frac AB \\
 6 & 0.49999935 & 0.33333291 & 1.49999994 \\
 5 & 0.49999350 & 0.33291359 & 1.50187172 \\
 4 & 0.49993503 & 0.33329132 & 1.49999415 \\
 3 & 0.49935089 & 0.33291359 & 1.49994145 \\
 2 & 0.49356674 & 0.32917327  & 1.49941316 \\
 1 & 0.44093099  & 0.29513643 & 1.49399036 \\
 0  & 0.20233616 & 0.14057702 & 1.43932605 \\
 -1 & 0.08944269 & 0.06611009 & 1.35293550 \\
 -2 & 0.07755340 & 0.05805909 & 1.33576667 \\
 -3 & 0.07637861 & 0.05725922 & 1.33390940 \\
 -4 & 0.07626130 & 0.05717930 & 1.33372220 \\
 -5 & 0.07624957 & 0.05717131 & 1.33370346 \\
 -6 & 0.07624840 & 0.05717051 & 1.33370159 \\
 -7 & 0.07624828 & 0.05717043 & 1.33370140 \\
 -8 & 0.07624827 & 0.05717042 & 1.33370138 \\
 -9  & 0.07624827 & 0.05717042 & 1.33370138 \\
 -10 & 0.07624827 & 0.05717042 & 1.33370138
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for the analysis, Claude. I don't see the blow up behaviour in your data, though.

Comment: @VortexSheet. I did not get any problem at all. It just works fine (at least to me).

Answer (score 0):

It seems the denominator is the problematic element here.

For the case of $\epsilon=0.00001$ and $h=10^6$, the denominator never approaches $0$:

[Graph of the denominator for $\epsilon=0.00001$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuTaz.jpg)

But as I increase the $\epsilon$ value to $\epsilon=0.0001$, it hits zero at $x=0.11$, which is exactly where the blow up occurs.

[Graph of the denominator for $\epsilon=0.0001$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXKjV.jpg)

But now the question is, if the denominator does reach $0$ at $x=0.11$, why does it blow up to a finite number? Shouldn't there be an aymptote at that location for $f(x)$?